# Error when trying to launch an executable .jar file

Tags: java

when in try to run jar file this error shown : "failed to load main-class manifest attribute from ..."
but when i run project in netbeans it`s run successfuly !!!

Answer (score 7):

If you want to run a JAR file directly (`java -jar program.jar`), you must set the `Main-Class` attribute in the manifest file. See http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html for details.

Otherwise, you need to set the JAR on the classpath instead and tell it the class to run. (`java -cp program.jar class.with.main.method`)

Comment: How to use ANT to build an executable .jar file for you: http://www.vertigrated.com/blog/2009/11/how-to-bundle-command-line-programs-into-a-single-executable-jar-file/